# Reading component state just after setting when using useState hook in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This `console.log` is not working: It'll just print the previous state value as `set` is `async`.

```
const SomeCompo = () => {
  const [count, set] = useState(0);
  const setFun = () => {
    console.log(count);
    set(count + 1);
    console.log(count);    
  }
  return <button onClick={setFun}>count: {count}</button>
}
```

I had to read the count in the render itself:

```
const SomeCompo = () => {
  const [count, set] = useState(0);
  console.log(count);
  const setFun = () => {
    set(count + 1);
  }
  return <button onClick={setFun}>count: {count}</button>
}
```

Is there a better way to read the value as I don't want to console for every render.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for this,

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(count);
}, [count]) //[count] is a dependency array, useEffect will run only when count changes.
```

Comment: useeffect will also run when the component first renders. If you only want to print changes from the initial value use a useref. e.g.:
`const renderCount = useRef(1);`, `  useEffect(() => {
    if (renderCount.current > 1 && broadcaster === true)
         console.log(count);
    renderCount.current = renderCount.current + 1;
  }, [count]);`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest **not to use setInterval**. I would do something like useEffect. This function will be called each time you do a setState. Just like you had callback after setState. Pass the `count` state in the array, it will watch only for the `count` change in the state and console your `count`.

```
useEffect(() => {
 console.log(count);
}, [count]);
```

Also if you dont need to rerender your other components, you might wanan use `useMemo` and `useCallback`.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Ls48dd-vJE

Here to more read: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: I never thought of using useEffect like that. Haven't used hooks that much as of now. Can you explain why not to use setInterval? Any performance related issue?

Answer (score 0):

The way to get a state value is to use `useEffect` and use the state as a dependency. This means that when we change a value the render cycle will finish and a new one will start, then `useEffect` will trigger:

```
useEffect( () => { console.log(value); }, [value] );
```

If you would need to read the value in the same cycle as it is changed a possibility could be to use the `useState` `set` function. This shows the latest value just before updating it:

```
setValue( latest_value => {
    const new_value = latest_value + 1;

    console.log(new_value);

    return new_value;
} );
```

Comment: `setValue( value => { console.log(value); return value + 1; } );` this will also print's the previous value only.

Comment: @ravibagul91 you are right, the idea is that we can use the last point where the old value exists.