# Why is my variable a different value in two different console.logs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

This is my code

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect')
    let database = firebase.database();
    database.ref().on('value', (snapshot) => { 
       console.log('hit'); 
       setQuestions(snapshot.val());
       console.log('questions here ', questions)
    }) 
  }, []);
  console.log(questions);
```

The output is

```
undefined
useEffect
undefined
hit
(15) [{...}] //This is questions being logged outside useEffect
questions here undefined
```

The console.log outputs are all over the place and aren't in order. Which I assume is because js is executed asynchronously. But what I don't get at all is how is the console.log outside useEffect logging `questions` as `(15) [{...}]` but then the console.log in useEffect, which is executed after logs `questions` as undefined. Is there a way I can fix this and make questions equal the array of objects when its logged in useEffect?

Comment: _"aren't in order"_ this is what being asynchronous means. You can't use state directly after setting it as setting state is asynchronous

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading component state just after setting when using useState hook in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58047171/reading-component-state-just-after-setting-when-using-usestate-hook-in-react)

Comment: I think `console.log(questions);` is the other two logs (it gets called on each render)

Comment: Asynchronous 101. You order a pizza. The one after useEffect tries to eat the pizza before it is made and delivered. The one inside sits waiting for the doorbell to ring and you can eat the pizza.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the console.log under setQuestions, gets executed prior to setQuestions finishing. Therefore it basically shows what questions is before you set it to be snapshot.val().

Comment: (I think this question has already [been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58047171/reading-component-state-just-after-setting-when-using-usestate-hook-in-react))